# Sql*loader How to check for range

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-loader

I want to put a range check in my control file, but I don't see any construct to do so. 
Using [DEFAULTIF](http://www.di.unipi.it/~ghelli/didattica/bdldoc/B19306_01/server.102/b14215/ldr_field_list.htm#i1009345) `DEFAULTIF my_col not between 0 and 1` sets the value of my_col to 0. as its defined as `number(12,8)`

Is there a way to set it to say -1 if the value is not in the range specified.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify any [expression](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14215/ldr_field_list.htm#i1008150) for the column. In your case, you can use CASE statement.

Sample:

```
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
(
my_col "case when :my_col not between 0 and 1 then -1 else to_number(:my_col) end"
)
```

Answer (score 1):

One can use functions within SQL*Loader provided they are within double quotes. Thus use a case statement in your control file.

```
my_col "CASE WHEN :my_col < i and :my_col > j THEN -1 ELSE :my_col END"
```